# How can I skip values of the foreach loop?

Tags: c#, mysql, foreach

I am using C# and developing and Application in Windows Form, my objective is compiler a chat with MySQL connection, where all the messages are save in a database and then in the computer, in a TXT.

Then, I will make a dynamic label which make a label for each line of the TXT.

```cs
sql.sqlcmd("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chat");
int count = int.Parse(sql.sqlcmd_answ);

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("mac.txt"))
{
    int i = 0;
    int p = 62;
    while (i < count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = line;
        lb.Location = new Point(58, p);
        p = p + 30;
        panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
        ++i; 
    }
}
```

The files has these lines:

> ```
> 1222
> 22222
> Chat...
> fxckxd
> fxckxd
> fxck
> ffff
> cambio
> Chat...heya
> 22222
> Xd
> Xd
> DDDD3EEEE
> DDDD
> ```

You can see that the *foreach* always print the first value, my TXT has 15 values, I would like that the TEXT of each label, were each line of the TXT.
 [image]

Comment: What's the value of `count`? It seems to me like you are adding the first value over and over again a ton of times because of that while loop.

Comment: You're repeating the value over the loop, creating an unnecessary loop within a loop.

The whole while loop can be removed altogether.

Comment: Try removing the while loop and try the Console.WriteLine in the foreach loop and then see whether you will achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because the value of `line` is the same for the entire life-time of the inner while loop. I can't see why do you even need the while loop. Simply iterate over the values in the file:

```
int p = 62;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("mac.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    var lb = new Label()
    {
       Text = line,
       Location = new Point(58, p)
    };
    panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
    p = p + 30;
}
```